# Limited number of bounding boxes in fasterRCNN PyTorch

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, object-detection, faster-rcnn

I use a pre-trained fasterRCNN from PyTorch to detect small obstacles in a 4k image. Currently I am facing some issues with false negatives, so objects are not detected.

I recognized that the number of **detected objects per image is always 100**, even tough there are more objects in the image. So is the number of objects limited in fasterRCNN?

```
    @staticmethod
    def create_new_faster_rcnn():

        import torchvision
        from torchvision.models.detection.faster_rcnn import FastRCNNPredictor
        from torchvision.models.detection.anchor_utils import AnchorGenerator

        anchor_sizes = ((8,), (16,), (32,), (64,), (128,),)
        aspect_ratios = ((0.5, 1.0, 2.0),) * len(anchor_sizes)
        rpn_anchor_generator = AnchorGenerator(
            anchor_sizes, aspect_ratios
        )
        model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(weights='DEFAULT', min_size=1400, max_size=3840, rpn_anchor_generator=rpn_anchor_generator)

        
        # get the number of input features for the classifier
        in_features = model.roi_heads.box_predictor.cls_score.in_features
        # replace the pre-trained head with a new one
        model.roi_heads.box_predictor = FastRCNNPredictor(in_features, len(trainImageManager.cfg.get("object_class_labels")))

        return model
```

Execution of fasterRCNN:

```
model.to(device)
result_dict = dict()

for image_batch, uuid_list, frame_number in data_loader:

    image_on_device = list(img.to(device) for img in image_batch)
    prediction_list = model(image_on_device)

    for pred, uuid in zip(prediction_list, uuid_list):
        labels = pred["labels"].detach().cpu().numpy()
        boxes = pred["boxes"].detach().cpu().numpy()
        scores = pred["scores"].detach().cpu().numpy()
        result_dict[uuid] = {"labels": labels, "boxes": boxes, "scores": scores}
```

Network-Layout:

```
FasterRCNN(
  (transform): GeneralizedRCNNTransform(
      Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
      Resize(min_size=(1400,), max_size=3840, mode='bilinear')
  )
  (backbone): BackboneWithFPN(
    (body): IntermediateLayerGetter(
      (conv1): Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=(7, 7), stride=(2, 2), padding=(3, 3), bias=False)
      (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(64, eps=0.0)
      (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
      (maxpool): MaxPool2d(kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, dilation=1, ceil_mode=False)
      (layer1): Sequential(
        (0): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(64, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(64, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            (0): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
            (1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(256, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(64, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(64, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(256, 64, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(64, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(64, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(64, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
      (layer2): Sequential(
        (0): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(256, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            (0): Conv2d(256, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
            (1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (3): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(512, 128, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(128, 128, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(128, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(128, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
      (layer3): Sequential(
        (0): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(512, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(1024, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            (0): Conv2d(512, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
            (1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(1024, eps=0.0)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(1024, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(1024, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (3): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(1024, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (4): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(1024, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (5): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(256, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(256, 1024, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(1024, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
      (layer4): Sequential(
        (0): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(1024, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(2048, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
          (downsample): Sequential(
            (0): Conv2d(1024, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(2, 2), bias=False)
            (1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(2048, eps=0.0)
          )
        )
        (1): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(2048, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(2048, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
        (2): Bottleneck(
          (conv1): Conv2d(2048, 512, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn1): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (conv2): Conv2d(512, 512, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn2): FrozenBatchNorm2d(512, eps=0.0)
          (conv3): Conv2d(512, 2048, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
          (bn3): FrozenBatchNorm2d(2048, eps=0.0)
          (relu): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
    )
    (fpn): FeaturePyramidNetwork(
      (inner_blocks): ModuleList(
        (0): Conv2dNormActivation(
          (0): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
        (1): Conv2dNormActivation(
          (0): Conv2d(512, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
        (2): Conv2dNormActivation(
          (0): Conv2d(1024, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
        (3): Conv2dNormActivation(
          (0): Conv2d(2048, 256, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
        )
      )
      (layer_blocks): ModuleList(
        (0): Conv2dNormActivation(
          (0): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        )
        (1): Conv2dNormActivation(
          (0): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        )
        (2): Conv2dNormActivation(
          (0): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        )
        (3): Conv2dNormActivation(
          (0): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
        )
      )
      (extra_blocks): LastLevelMaxPool()
    )
  )
  (rpn): RegionProposalNetwork(
    (anchor_generator): AnchorGenerator()
    (head): RPNHead(
      (conv): Sequential(
        (0): Conv2dNormActivation(
          (0): Conv2d(256, 256, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
          (1): ReLU(inplace=True)
        )
      )
      (cls_logits): Conv2d(256, 3, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
      (bbox_pred): Conv2d(256, 12, kernel_size=(1, 1), stride=(1, 1))
    )
  )
  (roi_heads): RoIHeads(
    (box_roi_pool): MultiScaleRoIAlign(featmap_names=['0', '1', '2', '3'], output_size=(7, 7), sampling_ratio=2)
    (box_head): TwoMLPHead(
      (fc6): Linear(in_features=12544, out_features=1024, bias=True)
      (fc7): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=1024, bias=True)
    )
    (box_predictor): FastRCNNPredictor(
      (cls_score): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=6, bias=True)
      (bbox_pred): Linear(in_features=1024, out_features=24, bias=True)
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

So after reading threw all parameter of faster-rcnn I really found exact this parameter:

```
       box_detections_per_img (int): maximum number of detections per image, for all classes.
```